# Python flask application returning None

Tags: python, html, sql, flask

Basically in application i am connecting to my sql database and trying to retrieve results for the inputs given by user which are `AGE`,`SEX` and `ADMITTING DIAGNOSIS CODE`.

I am able to give user input for both AGE and `SEX` and get the required results but when i give user input for `AGE`, `SEX` and `ADMITTING_DIAGNOSIS_CODE` my webpage returns `NONE` values.

Python code:

```
import MySQLdb
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask.ext.mysqldb import MySQL

app = Flask(__name__)

db = MySQLdb.connect("127.0.0.1","root","","health" )

@app.route("/", methods = ['GET','POST'])
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')




@app.route("/value", methods = ['GET','POST'])
def Authenticate():
    cursor = db.cursor()
    AGE = request.form['AGE']
    SEX = request.form['SEX']
    ADMITTING_DIAGNOSIS_CODE = request.form['ADMITTING_DIAGNOSIS_CODE']
    #DIAGNOSIS_CODE_1= request.args['DIAGNOSIS_CODE_1']

    sql = 'select avg(LENGTH_OF_STAY),avg(TOTAL_CHARGES),(select count(*) from health where AGE = %s and SEX = %s and ADMITTING_DIAGNOSIS_CODE = %s and DISCHARGE_STATUS = "A")/(count(*))*100 as alive,(select count(*) from health where AGE = %s and SEX = %s and ADMITTING_DIAGNOSIS_CODE = %s and DISCHARGE_STATUS = "B")/(count(*))*100 as dead from health where AGE = %s and SEX = %s and ADMITTING_DIAGNOSIS_CODE = %s'

    entries = []
    cursor.execute(sql,(AGE,SEX,ADMITTING_DIAGNOSIS_CODE,AGE,SEX,ADMITTING_DIAGNOSIS_CODE,AGE,SEX,ADMITTING_DIAGNOSIS_CODE,))

    # Fetch all the rows in a list of lists.
    results = cursor.fetchall()
    for row in results:
        entries.append(dict([('avg(LENGTH_OF_STAY)',row[0]),
                             ('avg(TOTAL_CHARGES)',row[1]),
                             ('dead',row[3]),
                             ('alive',row[2])

                             ]))

    return render_template('show_entries.html', entries=entries)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.debug = True
    app.run()
```

HTML CODE:

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Welcome</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1> Hello World!!!!</h1>
<form action="/value" method="post" enctype ="multipart/form-data">
<div>Enter the Age <input type="text" name="AGE" style="border: 1px solid black"></div>
<div>Enter the Sex <input type="text" name="SEX" style="border: 1px solid black"></div>
<div>Enter the code <input type="text" name="ADMITTING_DIAGNOSIS_CODE" style="border: 1px solid black"></div>



<div><input type="submit" value=" GO"></div>
</form>
</body>
</html>

<html>
<head>
<title> Welcome</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="/value" method="get" enctype ="multipart/form-data">
<table style="border: 1px solid black">
<tbody>
<tr>
<th width="35%" style="background-color: #CCFFCC; margin: 5px">Length of stay</th>
<th style="background-color: #CCFFCC; margin: 5px">Total charge</th>
<th style="background-color: #CCFFCC; margin: 5px">Alive</th>
<th style="background-color: #CCFFCC; margin: 5px">Dead</th>
</tr>
{% for entry in entries %}
<tr>
<td>{{ entry['avg(LENGTH_OF_STAY)'] }}</td>
<td>{{ entry['avg(TOTAL_CHARGES)'] }}</td>
<td>{{ entry['alive'] }}</td>
<td>{{ entry['dead'] }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</tbody>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

OUTPUT:

```
Length of stay  Total charge    Alive   Dead
None                None         None   None
```

Comment: Pull up your DB console and run the same query in it. More often than not, it is 1) a mix-up with the field names in code vs in your tables, 2) your actual data.

Comment: I jus tried the same with MySql it runs perfectly fine.

Comment: Hm. On the bottom form you are using a GET method, meaning your browser should send the form via URL parameters, which are AFAIK represented in Flask by the `request.args` dict, not `request.form`. Could that be it?

Comment: this didn't work. I just found out that there is something wrong with the ADMITTING DIAGNOSIS CODE part as i am able to run the application for AGE and SEX but when i try to run it for ADMITTING DIAGNOSIS CODE it returns me None.

Comment: So, in the end it _was_ your data, right?